# How can someone get a function arguments from an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm not very advanced in coding, but I want to do something like this:

```
function something(id){
    somethingElse(id);
    anotherThing(id);
}
var sampleArray:Array = [1,2,3];
something(1);
something(2);
something(3);
```

BUT, I want it to keep function with the argument of each item in the array one time no matter how long the array is.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can apply `function something(array_element)` to an arbitrary length array:

```
sampleArray.forEach(something);
```

It will not allow you to mutate the elements within the Array, however (unless they themselves contain references to other items and you're changing that).

REF: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Examples:

It's been a while since I messed with doing AS3.

The following is expected to be inside an AS3 class definition and provides a public function that takes a Vector of uints and
accumulates the greater than two uints:

```
private var _greater_than_two:Vector<uint>;

private function _append_greater_than_two(item:uint):void {
    if (item > 2) {
        _greater_than_two.push(item);
    }
}

// Ok, We're assuming that the array is strictly typed and full of uints.
public function collect_greater_than_twos(items:Vector<uint>) {
    // Append to the class instance _greater_than_two Vector any uint that is greater than two:
    items.forEach(_append_greater_than_two);

    // Tell us what is inside _greater_than_two now:
    trace("The _greater_than_two Vector has " + contents.join(', '));
}
```

Another use case may be to conditionally add to a Database. Let's assume we're building a MMORPG and you want to track how many times a player says "Hodor".

The below is, again, assuming this is inside a class (Let's call it Player):

```
private _redis:Redis; //assuming you filled this value in the constructor
private _playerName:String;

private function _detect_hodors(action:String):void {
    if (action.indexOf('Hodor') > -1) {
        _redis.incr(_playerName + 'actions', 1);
    }
}

public function process_user_actions(actions:Vector<String>):void {
    actions.forEach(_detect_hodors);
    // Do other things here...
}
```

A lot of companies will prefer you express the above in a simple for loop (assuming we're using the _append_greater_than_twos function from above):

```
function collect_greater_than_twos(items:Array):void {
    var index:uint;
    var item:uint;
    var end:uint = items.length;
    for (index=0; index < end; index++) {
        item = items[index] as uint;
        _append_greater_than_twos(item);
    }
}
```

When I was doing AS3, we avoided foreach constructs because they were much slower than using bare for loops and index accesses. Things could've changed since then though.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the usage? I'm not really good with these stuff.

Comment: Sure thing. Recall that a function has a name like a variable. My examples above assume you're using a Vector.<type>, but it easy ports over to Arrays (which really are just Vector.<*>'s).

Ultimately, you can use Array.forEach or simply write a for loop (shown in examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function something(id):void{
    somethingElse(id);
    anotherThing(id);
}
var sampleArray:Array = [1,2,3];
something(sampleArray[0]);
something(sampleArray[1]);
something(sampleArray[2]);
```